# Extract Domain Name form url Using REGEXP_REPLACE in the Mysql Version 8

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I am using latest version of `Server version: 8.0.11 MySQL Community Server - GPL`. [Download link](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/)

Table structure is `web_url < id, url >`

Sample Data in the url column.

www.google.com

www.yahoo.com

how to extract domain name only like `google` and `yahoo` using the function 
`REGEXP_REPLACE`. so it's meaning is the replace the `www.` and `.com` part be replace by space or with ''. if you have any other solution then you are welcome.

I am either missing some. So help.

I have written the regular expression but don't getting how use it properly in query. Please give query base answer.

my query

`select REGEXP_REPLACE(url,'^(www.)[a-zA-z0-9]*(.[a-zA-Z]{3})(\/[a-zA-Z09-]*)*','') from web_url;`

So far i done this query.

**So far i done this** may be someone get help 
done this query to test for comparison is happening or not.
**kindly ignore last two rows as they are just for testing purpose of `regexp_like` function**

`select regexp_like(url,'^(www.)(.*)(.com)$') from web_url;`

[image]

Answer (score -1):

If `url` is misleading and is in fact an FQDN, what the comments suggest,

```
reverse(regexp_replace(reverse(regexp_replace(url, '\\.[^\\.]*\\.?$', '')), '\\..*', ''))
```

should give you the second label from the right (or the third if there is the optional empty label at the end), what seems to be what you want.

The `reverse()` are necessary since we don't know how many dots are in the string. Because of the `reverse()` after we've removed the the last (or the last two) labels, we can simply remove from the first dot on.

If there were capture groups with `regexp_replace()` it would be easier, but I didn't find anything about that in the documentation. Please comment and point me to that, if I just missed that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it's almost giving solution may be something i doing wrong then let me know but this out put i got .  [output link](https://ibb.co/gPJ4DJ)

Comment: Huh? That's weird, it looks like the strings get concatenated? Please query the original string also.